# new roof with very noisy new power roof vent

Tags: roof, vent

Our most recent power roof vent wasn't working, so the roofer installed a new one. I don't recall these being so noisy though. I can hear it on my porch and inside my house. We've always had one in previous houses. Should I hear it inside the house?[video of power vent](https://youtu.be/pumeGXMPUSw)

Answer (score 2):

Power down the fan and check to see if the fan installation brochure is still attached to one of the fan blades with a rubber band. Happened to me once, and I am not kidding. It vibrated the whole house, and the $%#@*& roofer left the job site with it running like that.

If that's not the problem, it sure sounds like a dry bearing. What does the roofer say about it?

Comment: I could have guess the bearing or out of balance or loose mounting, but the instructions held on by a rubber band.  Hope no kids with sensitive ears were around.